# Is Regexp.new(user_input) in ruby secure?

Tags: ruby, security

Is it secure to create `Regexp` object from user-provided query directly, or do I need to do some validations on it first? Documentation doesn't say much one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound pretty good, if you allow to create any regex can be insecure (maybe cause DOS),since regexp can be cpu intensive.

I would avoid to my client to create their own regexp freely.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS

Comment: I'm aware of that problem, and I'm wrapping the search in `timeout` block. I just wonder if there are any code injection or such issues.